# Why has my Keynote presentation changed format to an index of unreadable .Iwa files?

Tags: macos, keynote

I transferred a presentation from an up-to-date iMac to my Macbook Air and it's changed from the original keynote document to this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of macOS, which version of Keynote is running on each Mac?

Comment: Version 12.1 on my Macbook Air. I don't know about the other Mac as it belonged to a company I no longer work for, but it was a new model. I just don't have those specs now.

Comment: what happens if you add „.key“ as an extension to the folder?

Comment: @slartibartfast I absolutely love you!!!

Answer (score 1):

An Apple Keynote document is basically a root folder with the extension *.key* containing a substructure of folders with Text, Images, Tables, Notes, Media, files, and XML-related data.

If the *.key*-extension is removed, MacOS will show such document package as a folder (with files and subfolders - see screen shot provided by OP).

To „reconstitute“/wrap such folder into a Keynote presentation it is often sufficient to add *.key* as extension to the root folder name.